# Enviar um token para API externa com request em Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, request, jwt, token

Sou novo em Node.js, estou com uma dúvida talvez fácil de resolver...
Tenho uma aplicação node.js que comunica com API externa em php, envio e recebo informações através de tokens, e encontrei um dilema ao utilizar o request, consigo enviar o token se coloco aspas duplas mas se coloco a variável token a API externa não reconhece.
Estou Utilizando request, jsonwebtoken e mysql, o interessante que quando envio um variável com menos caracteres funciona normalmente. Já tentei toString, concatenação, e nada. Segue Abaixo trecho do código:

```js
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const request = require('request');
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

                connection.query(tok.script, function (err, rows, fields2, res) {
                    if(err)
                        resjson = err;
                    else
                        resjson = rows;
                    cliente = {cliente:tok.sub};
                    const unirjson = Object.assign(cliente, resjson);
                    const token= jwt.sign(unirjson, 'senha');
                    const options2 = {
                        uri: 'https://meusite.com.br/api/semaforo',
                        method: 'POST',
                        json:{"token":token}
                    }
                    console.log(options2);
                    request(options2, function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 201) {
                            console.log("Deu Erro: " + error);
                        }
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                            console.log("Deu Certo: " + body);
                        }
                    }); 
                });
```

Comment: Você precisa realmente enviar o conteúdo do token ou ele é para autenticação na sua api externa?

Comment: Eu decidi enviar o token no corpo, para mais segurança, além da autenticação com o basic auth, já que será a resposta de uma consulta há um bd local.